# Order of fields in a Form

Tags: ordering, forms-7

How do I change the order my fields appear on the standard form in sharePoint 2013. I have changed the order in my customer list but they appear in a different order on my form.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you using a content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to List Settings and click on the Column Ordering link under the list of columns. This will allow you to reorder the columns as you'd like them.